# Error: Either make it static or add a no-args constructor to your class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running this class as testNG and getting error either make it static or add a no-args constructor. If I add no arg constructor, I get error: "implicit super constructor BaseClass() is undefined."

```
public class testmaven extends BaseClass{
public testmaven(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Test
public void myMethod() throws Exception {

    logInPage.openApp("Chrome","http://url.com");

}
```

**Here is the Base Class:**

```
public class BaseClass {
public WebDriver driver;
public boolean isDisplay;
public LogInPage logInPage;
public WaitForObj wait;
public DashboardPage dashboardPage;
public Actions action;
public Util util; 

public BaseClass(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    this.isDisplay = false;
    logInPage = new LogInPage(driver);
    wait = new WaitForObj(driver);
    dashboardPage = new DashboardPage(driver);
    util = new Util (driver);
    action = new Actions(driver);
}
```

**Here is the Login class**

```
 public class LogInPage extends BaseClass {
BrowserFactory browserfactory = new BrowserFactory();

public LogInPage(WebDriver driver){
    super(driver);
}    

public void openApp(String browserName, String env) throws Exception{

    driver = browserfactory.getBrowser(browserName);
    Log.info("Browser:" + browserName);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(env);
    Log.info("Env: " + env);
    wait.wait(1);
}
```

Comment: So you added the no-arg constructors LoginPage() and BaseClass(), and you're still seeing an error that BaseClass() is not there?

Comment: The answer given is correct. You should also adhere to the Java naming conventions, e.g., name your class `TestMaven`. Also, don't make member variables `public`, don't declare `throws Exception` in method signatures, and don't have types that perform very different purposes inherit from the same base class.

Comment: after adding no-arg constructor the error is gone, but i am getting Null pointer exception in  logInPage.openApp("Chrome","http://url.com"); of @Test Mymethod(). Any idea. what i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to explain to TestNG how it is supposed to instanciate your test class.

A solution is using a [`@Factory`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories).

Another solution, which is a more common pattern, is having an empty constructor and using [`@BeforeX` and/or `@AfterX`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) methods for the initialisation of attributes.

Comment: If i move  logInPage.openApp("Chrome","http://url.com");
 inside a new method @BeforeTest, i am getting null pointer error

Comment: `logInPage` must be initialized into a before method too AND `@BeforeTest` is not `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: I added this code in BeforeMethod but i am still getting null pointer. 
@BeforeMethod
 public void beforeTest() throws Exception{
  System.out.println("Test");
  
 }
Not sure how to format in code :(

Comment: NPE is due to not initialized loginPage variable.

Comment: LogInPage is initialized in Base Class. I also added a @beforeTest method, but i am still getting null pointer exception.

Comment: logInPage.openApp("Chrome","http://url.com"); line is throwing null pointer error.